# Using Oracle client OO4O in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, oracle, oracle-objects-ole

I have converted an existing vb6 app that uses Oracle client OO4O to VB.NET. AFter many many errors and warnings that I have fixed the program now runs. But I get the following warning on a build that I am unable to resolve:

> "Could not determine the dependencies of the COM reference OO4OAddin".

This is followed by a number of other warnings such as:

> "Processing COM reference OO4OAddin. Error while importing type: parameter referenced a type library that is not available (type: '_Connect'; parameter: 'VBInstance'; method: 'get_VBInstance')"

and

> "At least one of the arguments for '_IOraBlob._ReadCPP' cannot be marshaled by the runtime marshaler.  Such arguments will therefore be passed as a pointer and may require unsafe code to manipulate".

I have scanned the internet but get no matches on these errors. The OO4O DLL's are all registered. What is required to get these warnings resolved and what exactly do they mean?

Answer (score 0):

I know this isn't the answer you're looking for, but OO4O is discontinued and without any support from Oracle. It was never supported in Windows 7, nor in any 64 bit environment. I've seen some weird errors related to it in Windows 7 using the 32 bit client, where it's not properly registered by the installer. (In that case, fixing the registrations does usually make it start working, but that's not a viable long term solution.)

For a .net application, the best way to handle this going forward is to abandon it outright and port the application to ODP.net.